# Loop over an empty data frame in R and assign values to columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to define an empty dataframe with 5 columns and then using for loop, assign values to each column. I have written following lines:

```
k = 1:5
dfk = data.frame(k1 = c(), k2 = c(), k3 = c(), k4 = c(), k5 = c())
for (j in 1:5){
    for (i in 1:12){
        dfk[j] = c(dfk[j], i+j)
    }
    plot(1:12, dfk[j])
}
```

I am getting the following error:

"Error in `[.data.frame`(dfk, j): undefined columns selected
 Traceback:
 1. dfk[j]
 2. `[.data.frame`(dfk, j)
 3. stop("undefined columns selected")"

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 issues.

1. When you try to initialize `dfk` with `k1 = c()`, you get an empty logical vector. Later in the loop, when you try to combine that vector with an integer, you get a list, which can't be assigned to the `data.frame`. Instead set the columns to empty `vector()`s.
2. You need to assign values to `dfk` with two dimensional subsetting, or else the replacement gets to be the inappropriate length for the target. Therefore use `dfk[i,j]` to select one value and replace it with one value.
3. You call plot on `dfk[j]`,but that evaluates to a 12 row x 1 column data.frame. You could use `dfk[[j]]`.

```
k = 1:5
dfk = data.frame(k1 = vector(), k2 = vector(), k3 = vector(), k4 = vector(), k5 = vector())
for (j in 1:5){
    for (i in 1:12){
      dfk[i,j] = i+j
    }
  plot(1:12,dfk[[j]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.

```
dfk = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0))
colnames(dfk) <- c("k1","k2","k3","k4","k5")
for (j in 1:5){
  for (i in 1:12){
    dfk[i,j] = i+j
  }
  plot(1:12, dfk[,j])
}
```